# How do I pass non-string data to a named route in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have many screens, and I'm using the `Navigator`. I'd like to use "named routes", but I also need to pass non-string (such as images) to my next route.

I can't use `pushNamed()` because I can't pass non-string data to it.

How can I use a named route + send non-string data?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments This helped me

Answer (score 77):

**EDIT:**

It is now possible to pass complex arguments to `Navigator.pushNamed`:

```
String id;
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users', arguments: id);
```

It can then be used within `onGenerateRoute` to customize route building with these arguments:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Hooks Gallery',
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    final arguments = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/users':
        if (arguments is String) {
          // the details page for one specific user
          return UserDetails(arguments);
        }
        else {
          // a route showing the list of all users
          return UserList();
        }
      default:
        return null;
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: When the route is /myRoute/${myID} the path split has 3 items in the list with first being empty string "". Perhaps we have to ignore the path[0] and  make use of path[1] and path[2]?

Comment: I'd remove the first '/' in the route instead. But this is just an example, you're free to use whatever you want to.

Comment: True. I just wanted to add about the issue for the benefit of those visiting this later.

Comment: What if it's not id but an object? Can we do this?

Comment: Is the above answer still valid? I cannot see `arguments` property available via `RouteSettings`...

Comment: It has been added very recently. You may want to switch of channel.

Comment: @RémiRousselet - any hints where to find the channel / the most recent version of Navigator would be greatly appreciated. As of now, looking at https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteFactory.html doesn't expose any other properties than `initialRoute` and `name`. Let me know if I am wrong...

Comment: It is on `master` channel for now. It'll change over time, so I can't include that information in the answer. In theory, within a few months it should hit `beta` and a bit later `stable`.

Comment: Here is pull request for this feature: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27058

Comment: Shouldn't `UserDetails` and `UserList` be wrapped into an `MaterialPageRoute`?

Comment: Wrap the `switch` statement into `return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {<SWITCH STATEMENT>});` and it should work again.

Comment: @RémiRousselet how to manage navigation routing with tabbarview in flutter

Answer (score 38):

You can use the parameter `routes` of your App for directly passing arguments.

Like this:

```
  routes: {
    HomePage.route: (_) => HomePage(),
    DetailsPage.route: (context) =>
        DetailsPage(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments),
  },
```

In this case, the complete example will look like the next:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          initialRoute: HomePage.route,
          routes: {
            HomePage.route: (_) => HomePage(),
            DetailsPage.route: (context) =>
                DetailsPage(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments),
          },
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      static const String route = '/';

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/details',
                  arguments: ScreenArguments(
                    'My Details',
                    'Some Message',
                  ));
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
      static const String route = '/details';

      final ScreenArguments arguments;

      DetailsPage(this.arguments);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(arguments.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text(arguments.message),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class ScreenArguments {
      final String title;
      final String message;

      ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
    }
```

Comment: I think "initialRoute" is deprecated.

Answer (score 35):

**By Using Maps**

While pushing the arguments u can push that in map form and can do the same while extracting them.

e.g.

**While Pushing**

```html
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              'second',
              arguments: {
                'title':'This is a String',
                       or
                 'Fx': This could be any widget or Function
              }
```

**While Extracting** the arguments in the target page

```html
final routes=ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String,String>;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(routes['title']),
              ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Back"),
            onPressed: ()=>Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

and choose your map accordingly accordingly
```

Comment: best example for simple non generated Routes :)

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: 3rd April, 2021

This answer is old and Flutter navigation has evolved considerably since then. This may not be the best way to handle navigation with current versions, please consider other answers. I will leave this here for historical purposes.

---

Using `onGenerateRoute` it is easy to pass complex arguments on route transition with `Navigator.pushNamed` or `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`

A minimal setup to show the concept would be

### main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigator/routes.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Navigation Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => makeRoute(
                context: context,
                routeName: settings.name,
                arguments: settings.arguments,
              ),
          maintainState: true,
          fullscreenDialog: false,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### routes.dart

In the `_buildRoute` method we check the route name and cast arguments to a required type.

A draw back is that the type has to be defined before hand if required argument is not a simple type.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:navigator/list.dart';
import 'package:navigator/details.dart';

Widget makeRoute(
    {@required BuildContext context,
    @required String routeName,
    Object arguments}) {
  final Widget child =
      _buildRoute(context: context, routeName: routeName, arguments: arguments);
  return child;
}

Widget _buildRoute({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required String routeName,
  Object arguments,
}) {
  switch (routeName) {
    case '/':
      return ArticleList();
    case '/ArticleView':
      Article article = arguments as Article;
      return ArticleView(article: article);
    default:
      throw 'Route $routeName is not defined';
  }
}
```

Views

### list.dart

Construct the route argument using a defined type, `Article` in our case.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigator/details.dart' show Article;

class ArticleList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArticleListState createState() => _ArticleListState();
}

class _ArticleListState extends State<ArticleList> {
  List<Article> articles = [
    Article(
        id: 1,
        title: 'Article 1',
        author_name: 'Nilotpal',
        summary: 'Article 1 summary'),
    Article(
        id: 2,
        title: 'Article 2',
        author_name: 'Mike',
        summary: 'Article 2 summary'),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Articles'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('${articles[0].title}'),
              subtitle: Text('by ${articles[0].author_name}'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed('/ArticleView', arguments: articles[0]);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('${articles[1].title}'),
              subtitle: Text('by ${articles[1].author_name}'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed('/ArticleView', arguments: articles[1]);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### details.dart

Define a type for the arguments

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Article {
  final int id;
  final String author_name;
  final String title;
  final String summary;

  Article(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.author_name,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.summary});
}

class ArticleView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Article _article;

  ArticleView({@required Article article}) : _article = article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${_article.title}'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('${_article.author_name}'),
              Text('${_article.summary}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yikes on the minimal setup.

Answer (score 4):

The Flutter Cookbook shows how to navigate to a new page *and* pass non-string data to it.

[Passing data to next page](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

I started with `Navigator.pushedNamed()` because it was simple and I didn't have any data to pass.  When my needs changed and I wanted to pass data, I switched to `Navigator.push()`.

Example:

```
var nextPageData = {foo:'bar'};

Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
     MyNextPage(myData: nextPageData))
 );
```

Comment: How do I pass non-string data to a **named route** in Flutter?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use a named route navigator that has values as below

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/increaseBalanceAccountPage',
                        arguments: {'accountBalanceViewModel': result},);
```

so I should define that route in materialApp widget in the start of app but I should give parameters in the instance so I solve my problem with some modification of @YuriyLuchaninov code Like below:

```
MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: "/",
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => SplashScreenPage(),
      "/increaseBalanceAccountPage":

(context) =>
      UserAccountBalancePage(accountBalanceViewModel: Map<String,Object>
          .from(ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map).values.first as
      AccountBalanceViewModel)
},
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

I am capturing images with camera then passing them through to a confirmation page like so:

```
   ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source).then((File file) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MediaCaptured(file: file),
        ));
  });
```

You could easily do the same with any type of file or non-string data.

```
var foo = "non-string data";
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MediaCaptured(foo: foo),
        ));
```

Call the next page in the route by it's class name, as above.

Just make sure your new page accepts this in it's constructor.

```
 // Stateful Widget
class MediaCaptured extends StatefulWidget {
    MediaCaptured({ Key key, @required this.foo,}) : super(key: key);
    final var foo;
}

// StatelessWidget
class MediaCaptured extends StatelessWidget {
    MediaCaptured(this.foo);
    var foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the outcome of this problem, I developed the package

link: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/navigate

That provide to much your expect and easy to use

```
Navigate.navigate(context,
                      "home",
                      transactionType:TransactionType.fromLeft , // optional
                      replaceRoute: ReplaceRoute.thisOne, //optional
                      arg: {"transactionType":TransactionType.fromLeft,"replaceRoute":ReplaceRoute.thisOne} //optional
                      );
```

Answer (score 2):

From First StateFul class :

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/pending_order',arguments: {"staff" : staffObj});
```

To Second StateFul class :

```
  class PendingOrders extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PendingOrdersState createState() => _PendingOrdersState();
}

class _PendingOrdersState extends State<PendingOrders> {
  StaffModel staffModelObj;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routes =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (routes != null) {
      staffModelObj = routes["staff"];
    }
    return Scaffold(...);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this trivial example from flutter. You have a class created as follows

```
class ScreenArguments {
   final String title;
   final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

Now we will pass an object of this class as an argument as follows

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
  arguments: ScreenArguments(
    'Extract Arguments Screen',
    'This message is extracted in the build method.',
  ),
);
```

And then you can extract the arguments as follows

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
```

And that is all. Hope this helps Source: [passing arguments to a named route](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

```html
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              'second',
              arguments: {
                'title':'This is a String',
                       or
                 'Fx': This could be any widget or Function
              }
```

Answer (score -5):

```
We can pass any type of arguments when declaring routes as constructor arguments as below,

For example to send a list of Strings,

List<String> titles = [];

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        home: new FirstPage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/SecondPage": (BuildContext context) => new SecondPage(titles),
        },
      ),
    );

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/SecondPage');
      }),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> titles;

  SecondPage(this.titles);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(titles[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```