# Dynamic navigation routes

Tags: flutter

I have an app that I would like to try and remake in a flutter. In this app, the navigation routes change a lot and are not defined in a centralized place, but instead is defined by different developers in different "micro-projects" that are then bound together in the main app.

So my question is: Can I somehow dynamically set the routes on a MaterialApp at runtime? So that when a given widget class is loaded, it takes the MaterialApp instance and sets a new Map of routes on to the MaterialApp, and any routes that were before are now gone and replaced with new routes?

Comment: this question is in fact the same a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419908/how-do-i-pass-non-string-data-to-a-named-route-in-flutter/47420619#47420619

The title is not exactly the same, but the answer is : dynamic routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a property on `MaterialApp` to handle dynamic routing : `onGenerateRoute`

For example if you do

```
onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
 if (condition) {
   return new MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => new MyPage(),
     settings: routeSettings,
   );
 }
 // fallback route here
},
```

This will handle *all* routes even if they are not statically defined, as long as they match `condition`

But remember that Flutter forbid the usage of `dart:mirror`. Which means that if you want to push things further you'd have to use a code generator. Combined to a decorator, you can make that whenever you write :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int prop;

  @MyNavigation
  MyWidget({this.prop});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

it will automatically generate the code to handle the route `/mywidget/{prop}`.

Comment: I'm trying to put my routes into a static route table and am struggling with the syntax. The documentation on anything with flutter that's not in a tutorial is god awful imo. 

How do you get a WidgetBuilder from a widget?