# How to pass object to StatefulWidget while Routing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have **MyApp** class which is responsible for loading application. I'm loading a Class **HomeWidget** as home in MyApp.

```
void main() => runApp(new myApp());
class myApp extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return new MaterialApp(
             title: 'My App',
             color: Colors.grey,
             home: new HomeWidget(),
             theme: new ThemeData(
               primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
             ),
             routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                 "/ItemDetailWidget": (BuildContext context) => new MovieDetailsPage(),
    },
);}}
```

HomeWidget contains - Header, ListView, BottomNavigation.

When user taps particular item from ListView, I wanted to show new Widget/Page(**ItemDetailWidget**) which has all information about that particular item.

So i created **ItemDetailWidget** which is stateful and it accepts one parameter which is of type Object **MyModel** suppose. I made it stateful for purpose.

> How should i add ItemDetailWidget into Routes as i'm passing
>   parameter to it?

I tried using

```
        "/ItemDetailWidget": (BuildContext context) => new ItemDetailWidget(),
```

However, It throwing error as "**The Constructor return type dynamic that isn't of expected type widget**"

& Also how can i pass MyModel object to ItemDetailWidget using Navigator syntax? I'm having onTap() function in ListView.

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget1');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the data you're sending; it sounds like in your case you have a bunch of movie details in a DB (or something), and you want to be able to show details for that movie. What you can do is use a unique identifier for each movie, and put that in the request; this is described more or less in the [potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419908/how-do-i-pass-non-string-data-to-a-named-route-in-flutter) mentioned in the comments. The flutter [stocks example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419908/how-do-i-pass-non-string-data-to-a-named-route-in-flutter) also explains this.

To summarize:

1. When you push, do a `pushNamed("moviedetails/${movieUniqueIdentifier}")`.
2. In your MaterialApp, you can set

routes:

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
     '/':         (BuildContext context) => new Movie(movies, _configuration),
     '/settings': (BuildContext context) => new MovieSettings(_configuration)
  },
```

and:

```
onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
  if (routeSettings.name.startsWith("movie:") {
     // parse out movie, get data, etc
  }
}
```

---

However, this isn't always the easiest way of doing things - say for example your database takes a while to respond and so you want to do a query before and then pass in the result (caching would be a good answer to this but let's ignore that for now =D). I'd still recommend the first method, but there are cases where it doesn't work.

To instead pass an object directly in (as the question actually asks) you can use:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: 
  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
  // directly construct the your widget here with whatever object you want
  // to pass in.
})
```

Note that this will get quite messy if you have these `Navigator.of(context).push` blocks all over your code; I got away from this by using static convenience methods to it such as `MyNavigator.pushMovie(context, movieObject)` which would call `Navigator.of(context)....` under the hood. (I also subclass Navigator and so do MyNavigator.of(context) instead, but my setup is complicated as it does a bunch of additional custom navigation stuff).