# Tabbar with unique actions per tab

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Tabbar` with two tabs. The `Tabbar` has its own `Appbar` which is used by both tabs. How do I have the sort button run custom (set state) functions inside each tab's stateful widget? Alternatively, is it possible for each tab to have its own unique `Appbar`? I am not sure what best approach is here.

[image]

*Example method inside one of the tabs:*

```dart
class _TabAState extends State<TabA> {
  void sort() {
    setState(() {
    myList.sort((a, b) => b.dueDate.compareTo(a.dueDate));
    });
  }

...
```

*Sort button:*

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
  onPressed: () => DefaultTabController.of(context).index == 0
      ? TabA.sort() // Does not work
      : TabB.sort(), // Does not work
),
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. You want to have 2 different AppBars on the parent that holds the TabBar depending on which Tab is selected?

Comment: Two different app bars was just one approach I thought may make this possible. Ultimately, I want to run a sort function which is called from an appbar button. However, the sort function needs to run a specific function inside of the stateful tab widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your concern if this approach is the best approach:

**From the documentation**

> The Scaffold was designed to be the single top level container for a MaterialApp and it's typically not necessary to nest scaffolds.

Based from this statement, I suggest that it's probably not a good idea to nest multiple `Scaffold` inside another `Scaffold`. This is related to your concern, whether to have nested `AppBar` inside a `Scaffold`, given that you can only have one `AppBar` per `Scaffold`.

I personally **do not recommend** the calling static or non static method from **other** Flutter `Widget` classes (eg. widget that serves as a standalone screen for your app) for executing the business logic of your application. Perhaps, you can continue implementing the business logic of your application using widgets such as `ScopedModel` and architectural patterns such as BloC, Redux or Mobx.

**Further reading:**

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html
- https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/04/bloc---scopedmodel---redux---comparison/
- [How to call method from another class in Flutter(Dart)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549440/how-to-call-method-from-another-class-in-flutterdart)

Comment: Thank you for this information. This is my first mobile application and had to take a deep dive into state management options yesterday and today. I got it working by utilizing the `provider` package and storing my list in a more global/accessible location which then uses `notifyListeners()` to update to list in the tab.

Comment: Great. That's good thing to know. Yes, `provider` does the job as well for you case.

Comment: Hey, I'm having a similar problem, could anyone give an opinion on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392702/how-to-implement-the-search-action-for-each-tab-in-tabbar