# Call _method not producing result Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The issue seems to be around calling a method with a `_` before it, such as `Future _showFirstPolylineMapMarkers`

In my main.dart at the end of a method I call 2 entities, one is within main.dart and works fine, the other is in another Class, `_mapItemsExample2`.

```
...
       _sendIntermodalDataToSecondScreen(context, mappedValues, dest);       //works fine
       _mapItemsExample2?.getroute(deplat, deplong, deplocname);

      }
    });
  }
```

It will pass data to

```
  Future getroute(deplat, deplong, deplocname) async {
    print('getroutetest');
    _showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname); 
  }

  void _showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname) async {
...
```

But it goes dead and doesn't print or call `_showFirstPolylineMapMarkers`

If i replace `.getroute...` with `._showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname)` to call the method directly it shows an error

```
The method '_showFirstPolylineMapMarkers' isn't defined for the type 'MapItemsExample2'.
```

If i remove the underscore at the start `_` errors go away but it doesnt call it when ran

Any guidance appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `_` indicates a private field or method, meaning that it can only be used within the file it's defined in.

It is a good practice to use the `_` to make methods private to ensure they're only used where they are defined.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the explanation. I have removed the ```_``` concerned with this process and on code running it doesn't produce any results of ```print``` to show the the method has been called still

Comment: to call a public function from an other class, first need to make an object of this class

Comment: @JaveedIshaq Okay, how do I do that? Can't find a clear example on Google

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549440/how-to-call-method-from-another-class-in-flutterdart)  @al246

Comment: @amo Thanks I have seen that Q previously but the response was referencing an 'onTap' scenerio, is it the same principle? Thank you

Comment: https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-object try looking into this if it might help :)