# How to push the contents of custom widget to next page

Tags: dart, flutter, state, custom-widgets

I have created widget and called the parameters in a column with Gridview.count, but i want to push the same parameters to another screen. Please how will I do it? Thanks

```
child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                primary: false,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Hero(
                    tag: 'f2',
                    child: flashCard('images/flashSales/f2.jpg', 'Iphone 8, 126gb ram','Ghs 2,150', 'Newsite, Takoradi', '8 Available', true),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ]),
      )
    ]));
```

}

```
  Widget flashCard(String pixPath, String heading, String price,
  String location, String available, bool inStock) {
return Container(
  width: 170.0,
  child: new Card(
    elevation: 2.0,
    child: Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(pixPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,),

            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to pass data or arguments between flutter app screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015775/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-data-or-arguments-between-flutter-app-screens)

Comment: sorry I didn't check that post before posting mine. Thanks